# jquery sweet alert add detail button

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I need to show sweet alert with button that says 'detail' and by clicking this button, user can be redirected to another page. I want it to preserve style of 'error' sweet alert. Is it possible?

```
swal({
  title: "Sorry but error occurred",
  text: "Sorry but error occurred",
  type: "error",
  allowEscapeKey: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: check the snnipet

```js
sweetAlert({
            title: "Sorry but error occurred",
            text: "Sorry but error occurred",
            type: "error",
            allowEscapeKey: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Detail",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: true
            }, function (isConfirm) {
               if (isConfirm) {
                  window.location.href  ="www.yoururl.com/index.php";
               }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I haven't managed to open in in a new window, user window.open instead. Thanks